# The image of ec2 instance is still considering the original data of application.yml and database.yml of parent ec2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

First I launched a EC2 instance for setting up the proper environment for a rails application production deployment. So the deployment worked. Then I created an image of that ec2 instance for official production deployment. In new image I changed the data of:

**deploy@ip-162-35-33-216:~/apps/appname/shared/config$ vi application.yml**

And I also changed the database.yml file in the same path. But it is STILL CONSIDERING THE DATA OF PARENT EC2 INSTANCE. 
Could somebody please tell me how can I solve this issue?

Adding more details:

On my parent ec2 instance the application.yml looked like this:

```
SMTP_ADDRESS: 'smtp.gmail.com'
SMTP_PORT: 587
SMTP_DOMAIN: 'domain.com'
SMTP_USERNAME: 'first_username@gmail.com'
SMTP_PASSWORD: 'password'
SUPER_ADMIN_EMAIL: 'super_admin@mailinator.com'
```

So when I sent emails from the app, they were being delivered from first_user@gmail.com.

And then I created an image of that parent instance and I deployed a replica of the same application.
First I deleted the existing app data except Mysql,nginx and rvm (since the image inherits data from the parent instance) on the image and changed the contents of application.yml  to the following.

```
SMTP_ADDRESS: 'smtp.gmail.com'
SMTP_PORT: 587
SMTP_DOMAIN: 'domain.com'
SMTP_USERNAME: 'second_username@gmail.com'
SMTP_PASSWORD: 'password'
SUPER_ADMIN_EMAIL: 'super_admin@mailinator.com'
```

And when I sent the email from the new deployed app from image instance, the emails where still being delivered from "first_username@gmail.com" where as it should be delivering from "second_username@gmail.com".

Comment: could you give us more informations and include relevant code? Thanks

Comment: "created an image of that ec2 instance " : -- Please explain this. Do you mean you create an AMI out of it? Or you just create a snapshot of the instance ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your changing of `application.yml` is not applied. Changing data of `application.yml` is not applied instantly. When restart puma, then will be applied.

If you use capistrano, run `cap production deploy:restart`.
Or you can run `pumactl restart` on the production server.